# Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER error: ORA-27369. exit code 7

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I try to run external script with Oracle Database whit DBMS_SCHEDULER.

I created a job:

```
BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB( job_name => 'MODPY_JOB',
        job_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
        job_action => 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe',
        job_class => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
        comments => 'Job to call batch script on Windows',
        auto_drop => FALSE,
        number_of_arguments => 3,
        enabled => FALSE);

    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE( job_name => 'MODPY_JOB', argument_position => 1, argument_value => '/q'); 
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE( job_name => 'MODPY_JOB', argument_position => 2, argument_value => '/c'); 
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE( job_name => 'MODPY_JOB', argument_position => 3, argument_value => 'C:\m.bat >nul'); 
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE( 'MODPY_JOB' ); 
END;
```

I tried to run it:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(
    JOB_NAME            => 'MODPY_JOB',
    USE_CURRENT_SESSION => TRUE);
END;
```

I got this error:

```
ORA-27370:  job slave failed to launch a job of type EXECUTABLE
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:accessing job scheduler service failed with status: 2
ORA-27301: OS failure message: No such file or directory
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sjsec 6a
ORA-27303: additional information: The system cannot find the file specified.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 209.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 594.
ORA-06512: at line 2.
27370. 00000 -  "job slave failed to launch a job of type EXECUTABLE"
    *Cause:    The scheduler ran into an error when the job slave tried to start
               a job of type EXECUTABLE. The rest of the error stack will provide
               more detailed information on what the exact problem was.
    *Action:   Correct the problem specified in the error stack and reschedule
               the job.
```

I made a credential to solve the problem:

```
begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_credential(
    CREDENTIAL_NAME => 'NAME',
    USERNAME => 'user',
    PASSWORD => 'pswd',
    WINDOWS_DOMAIN  => 'localdomain');
end;
```

After that, I gave credential details to the job:

```
begin
    dbms_scheduler.set_attribute('MODPY_JOB','credential_name','NAME');
end;
/
```

When I run try to run the job again, I got this error:

```
    Error report -
ORA-27369:  job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: 7 !@#--!@#7#@!--#@!
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 209.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 594.
ORA-06512: at line 2. 
27369. 00000 -  "job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: %s" 
    *Cause:    A problem was encountered while running a job of type EXECUTABLE.
               The cause of the actual problem is identified by the exit code.
    *Action:   Correct the cause of the exit code and reschedule the job.
```

I tried to run this on Windows OS, and I got Oracle Database 12.

Where is the problem? How can I fix this and run external file with oracle?

Comment: Something is wrong with credentials. What are you puting in WINDOWS_DOMAIN  ?

Comment: I tried to run it with credential that has got WINDOWS_DOMAIN part. (So it was null.) It didn't work. (ORA-27369 exit code 9)
Then I put 'LOCALDOMAIN' to WINDOWS_DOMAIN. 
As I saw WINDOWS_DOMAIN can be null. Maybe I make mistake other way...

Comment: Maybe your user has different domain. Go to cmd -> run: set user. The command will print  userdomain and userdnsdomain. Try both.